# Bind factory data to angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

How do I bind the array (conversations) to ng-repeat within the controller below. I've tried binding it in a function, the intent is for this to run when the controller loads up and then bind the data to the view.

Any help appreciated.

```
.factory('UserMessages', function ($q, $http) {
var conversations = [];
return {
    getMessages: function () {
        var userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userdata")), userID = userdata.ID;
        $http.get('api/Messages/GetUserConversations?id=' + userID)
        .then(function (data) {
            conversations = data.data;
            return conversations;
        })
    }
}
})
```

The controller:

```
    .controller('MessagingCtrl', function ($scope, $http, UserMessages, $stateParams, TruckersOnlyUrl) {
console.log('MessagingCtrl loaded.');

UserMessages.getMessages();
});
```

This isn't a syntax issue as the data is being returned and I've logged it in the console successfully, I just can't figure out how to render it to the view.

I've tried:

```
    $scope.msgs = UsersMessages.getMessages();
```

but no luck.

**UPDATE- ANSWER**

```
UserMessages.getMessages().then(function (conversations) {
    $scope.conversations = conversations;
});

.factory('UserMessages', function ($q, $http) {
var getMessages = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userdata")), userID = userdata.ID;

    $http.get('api/Messages/GetUserConversations?id=' + userID)
    .then(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
  };

 return {
    getMessages: getMessages
 };
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise from the $http call in the service, and in your controller add a.then handler to the service method call.  In the then handler update your scope property FTW

Comment: Did a quick google search on what you recommended and came across http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/ blog post which gave me something to look at. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sure no problem. The upgrading to promises section demonstrates what I was describing. I'm not sure I'd suggest binding a scope value to a promise as described in the last section. It moves more logic into the view and could be more difficult to unit test.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here, mostly stemming from a misunderstanding of how an asynchronous function works in javascript.

In this part:

```
.then(function (data) {
        conversations = data.data;
        return conversations;
})
```

You're actually not returning conversations from the getConversations call, because the code within the anonymous function is being executed asynchronously. Instead you're returning null from that call.

To oversimplify this, you could do the following:

```
getMessages: function () {
        var userdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userdata")), userID = userdata.ID;
        $http.get('api/Messages/GetUserConversations?id=' + userID)
        .then(function (data) {
            angular.copy(data.data, conversations);
        })
        return conversations;
 }
```

What this does is return the conversation object (unpopulated), but once the http request comes back populates it -- using angular.copy avoids  changing the reference which would otherwise happen if you just used the '=' operator.

Comment: Okay, I'll admit my understanding of promises is still in its infant stage :(    Using angular.copy and then returning the conversations array how does it become accessible in the controller though? I still can't get the view to update properly.